# Magento 2 Cron jobs are stuck in Pending status

Tags: magento2, crontab, magento-cron, magento2.4.3.p1, cronjobs

We have use Magento:2.4.3-p1 version , my issue is new cron generating but "pending" status.
After attempting to update product attributes in bulk I have a "stuck" system message of
[Task "Update attributes for 1 selected products": 0 item(s) have been scheduled for update.]
This has been in "Pending, in queue" status.

- Steps to Genarating issue.

1.In Admin navigate to Catalog -> Products page.

2. Select all products.
3. In drop-down 'Actions' menu select "Update attributes"
4. Change desired value of any attribute (like description) and save.

issue Screenshot : https://i.imgur.com/zYyB3Nm.png

any idea about issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup cron job properly and running well than it will be processed automatically but if you don't want to wait for cron job running than just try to manually process queue the following commands.

```
bin/magento cron:run
```

after running above command still not updated the attributes following the below command

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:list
```

it will shows queue consumners list like product_action_attribute.update, product_action_attribute.website.update, etc. pass that queue name after queue:consumers:start [name]

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update
```

Hope this can help.